# Does this test case break the shunting yard algorithm? "1*2-3/4+5*6-7*8+9/10"

Tags: rpn

I have tried numerous times to solve the following using the shunting yard algorithm: `1*2-3/4+5*6-7*8+9/10`

Infix Notation:

```
"1*2-3/4+5*6-7*8+9/10"
```

Postfix Notation:

```
[1,2,*,3,4,/,5,6,*,7,8,*,9,10,/,+,-,+,-]
```

The correct answer is `-24`.

Every time I solve the postfix notation version of this I get `28`.

I have yet to find a working RPN calculator online ... So I have turned to stack overflow.

Comment: First of all, are you aware that your postfix notation translates back to `1*2-(3/4+5/6-(7*8+9/10))`? Which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: As a simpler example, try applying the algorithm to `1-2+3`.  Make sure you get `[1,2,-,3,+]`.  The erroneous logic you're applying sounds like it would give you `[1,2,3,+,-]`.  If you can't see where you're going wrong, write out a step-by-step explanation of your logic, and edit your question to include it.

Comment: Following the version of the algorithm at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm, I get postfix that starts out `[1,2,*,3,4,/,-,...]`.  When you process the first `+`, you have `-,/` on the operator stack.  You pop `/` because it has higher precedence than `+`.  You also pop `-` because it has the same precedence as `+` and is left associative.  I think this last part is what you may be missing.

Comment: This is an old question, but I just wonder why you say the correct answer should be -24. It's clearly a sum of integers EXCEPT for 3/4 and 9/10 whose decimal parts do not "cancel out", so IMHO the result can by no means be an integer.

Comment: @PhilippImhof: I assumed that `/` is doing truncating integer division, so `3/4` and `9/10` are both 0.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on my own Shunting Yard algorithm, and so this might not be 100% correct, but I what Im getting is `[ 1, 2, *, 3, 4, /, -, 5, 6, *, +, 7, 8, *, -, 9, 10, /, +]` The Wikipedia for [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20the%20shunting,abstract%20syntax%20tree%20(AST).) gives the pseudo code for this parsing, and I dont think I could explain it better. As some alredy said, you might want to look into how precedence and associativity affect parsing.